# How to use Semantic UI installed via Npm?

Tags: node.js, express, semantic-ui

I've just installed Semantic UI in my cloud9 instance via Npm using `npm install --save semantic-ui` But I got no way to use it. Do I need to require it? I got a new directory called `semantic` But What do I do with this?

Comment: If you're only using it without extensive modification/configuration of it, why not follow the "Simpler Setup" section suggested in the official documentation https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html and `npm install semantic-ui-css` or `semantic-ui-less` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go into the `semantic` folder and build it with Gulp.

After building it the necessary css and js files can be accessed in your html `<head>` section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

See details [here](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) in section 'Install Semantic UI'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what is Gulp? I'm sorry. I'm kinda super-newbie in this area.

Comment: It's a task runner - a tool to help structure and organise your project in many ways.  In this case you simply need it to run a single command - `build`. Semantic takes care of the rest for you. Install it by running `npm install -g gulp`